# Won't River Song and the Doctor still have to have some sort of relationship in the next series?

Tags: doctor-who, river-song, marriage

I know that they got married in an alternative universe and it didn't count. But what about his name? In 'Silence in the Library' the Doctor says there's only one time he could tell her his name and if he didn't in 'The Wedding of River Song' then when did he? Moffat has got himself into a pickle if he doesn't look into this, because how did she know his name in 'The Name of the Doctor '? I know he's got a life offscreen with her but why is he still surprised that she knows his name?

Another thing is he still hasn't met her for the first time because in 'The Impossible Astronaut' she tells Rory when she first met the doctor, he knew everything about her but in 'Let's Kill Hitler' when she supposedly 'first meets him' he's only just finding out about her and he definitely doesn't know every last thing about her, does he?

Answer (score 4):

It seems unlikely that River Song will appear, at least not regularly, in the 12th Doctor's tenure.

We have seen almost all of River's life on-screen, and other than her single appearance in *Forest of the Dead / Silence in the Library*, she was with the 11th Doctor:

- She was born in *A Good Man Goes To War*, and was kidnapped by The Silence
- She grows into a small child in their captivity, as seen in *The Impossible Astronaut / Day of the Moon*, where she escapes and regenerates into Mels.
- She grows up into a teen-aged Mels with Rory/Amy, then regenerates into River Song, as seen in *Let's Kill Hitler*.
- At the end of *Closing Time* we see her, now with a Ph. D in archaeology, kidnapped again by The Silence.
- She "kills" The Doctor in *The Impossible Astronaut* and/or *Wedding of River Song*, at which point she is imprisoned in Stormcage.
- She escapes from Stormcage numerous times, and eventually gets pardoned, each time progressively later in her life but earlier in The Doctor's life, as seen in *The Pandorica Opens* or *Time of the Angels*, for example.
- In the mini-episode "Last Night" we see The Doctor's last "date" with River, as the "third" (future-most) River tells The Doctor that he's taking her to the Singing Towers of Darillium.
- The next time she sees The Doctor is at The Library, where she dies.

Note that, when she meets The 10th Doctor, she immediately concludes that it's "very early days" for him because of his face. This is, as far as we know, the only time she meets this incarnation, so she probably doesn't recognize him directly. The most logical conclusion is that *she* knows she never meets any of his future incarnations, so any one besides the 11th must be earlier.

It's possible that she may appear in episodes of the 12th Doctor's lifetime, but so far we've seen no real indication of that. She's been notably absent from the shows since The Doctor lost Amy and Rory; her only appearance was as her deceased saved essence. To me, this implies that Moffet is trying to write her out of the series.

As far as the specific events you mentioned:

- We almost have to assume at this point that she was told his name off-screen; perhaps they had a more formal wedding ceremony at some point, since their wedding in *Wedding of River Song* arguably never happened, and was rushed anyway.
- River forgot almost everything that happened between her and The Doctor prior to "killing" him in *The Impossible Astronaut*, at which point he did know almost everything about her. But even in *Let's Kill Hitler* he knew a good amount about her future, enough to seem like he knew "everything".

Comment: She did get a mention in The Time Of The Doctor, but I don't know if that counts.

Comment: @MrLister: When was River mentioned in _The Time of the Doctor_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When he's talking to Tasha Lem about how they tried to stop him. TASHA: "They engineered a psychopath to kill you."
ELEVEN: "Totally married her. I’d never have made it here alive without River Song." [Transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-16.html).

Comment: @MrLister: Thanks